# Powershell Split a file name

Tags: powershell, split, get-childitem

I have to copy the files of diferent directories in their directory changing their name. I have some problems with the command split.

The variable $nom contains all the files in a directory: example:
a.out b.out c.out
Then I want to cut the first word. "a" -> a.out

But when I try to do this it stores also a " ".

Because when I execute write-host $nomArxiu it prints:
a _directory1.out and my final resultat has to be a_directory1.out

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of `-split` is an array.

You only want one field not both (which you get when you use `$test0`.

Try `$test0[0]`.

Or use a more appropriate function for this:

```
$shortnom = $_ -replace ".out$",""
```

or (since `$_` is an `IO.FileInfo` object just use its `BaseName` property):

```
write-host $_.basename
```

Comment: `$nom` already is a list of `FileInfo` objects. No need for extra casting. He could simply do `$_.BaseName + '_' + $item.Name + $_.Extension`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Good point. I was testing this manually so had strings.